# add response data from a post request to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm working on an inventory management system and when I click the save button to add a new item, I want to take that response data and set state with all of the previous items, plus the newly added one so I don't have to refresh the page to see changes.

Here is the code that handles the post request:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const RESET_VALUES = {id: '', category: '', price: '', name: ''}

class ProductForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            product: Object.assign({}, RESET_VALUES),
            errors: {}
        }
    }
        
    handleChange(e) {
        const target = e.target
        const value = target.value
        const name = target.name
    
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            prevState.product[name] = value
            return { product: prevState.product }
        })
    }
    
 
    handleSave = async (e) => {
      //this.props.onSave();
      e.preventDefault();
        
        const backendURL = 'http://localhost:5000/product/create'; 
        const { product } = this.state;
      
        try {
          const response = await fetch(backendURL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(product)
          });
      
          if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json(); // Extract response data
            console.log(data)

            this.setState(prevState => ({
              products: { ...prevState.products, [data._id]: data},
              product: { ...RESET_VALUES },
              errors: {} // Reset errors if needed
            }));
             
            // Handle success - e.g., show a success message
            console.log('Product saved successfully!',product);
            
          } else {
            // Handle error - e.g., show an error message
            console.error('Error saving product:', response.statusText);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error.message);
          // Handle network errors or other exceptions
        }
         
      };
      
    render () {
        return (
            <form>
                <h4>Add a new product</h4>
                <p>
                    <label>Name <br /> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.product.name} /></label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Category <br /> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.product.category} /></label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Price <br /> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.product.price} /></label>
                </p>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" onClick={this.handleSave}></input>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default ProductForm
```

here is what the response data looks like: `{ "id": null, "product": { "productid": null, "category": "7", "price": 7, "name": "mario", "instock": true }, "_id": "65720598b1e57eb76e2f5658", "__v": 0 }`

the state is just an array of the same object I am trying to add to state

I tried to look at other examples of how to set new state while keeping the previous state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in `handleChange()` is likely not correct:

```js
this.setState((prevState) => {
    prevState.product[name] = value
    return { product: prevState.product }
})
```

That code would replace all of your `state` with just `{ product: prevState.product }`.  The rest of your fields would be clobbered.  Also that code is treating the object in state as though it is mutable which React says [you should not do](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#whats-a-mutation).

Instead you likely want copy the state object:

```js
this.setState((prevState) => {
  let newVal = {...prevState}; // do a "shallow copy" to a new object
  newVal.product[name] = value; // update the new object
  return newVal; // return the new object
})
```

All that said, you haven't identified what is wrong behaviour in your above code.  You hinted at it, but I'm totally guessing as to what (mis)behaviour we are trying to fix for you.